# C check if file has executable permission returns false

Tags: c, file, file-permissions

I have a function which checks if a user has `-x` permission for a file or not.

```c
static int is_executable_file(const char *file) {
    struct stat sb;
    
    printf("\nis_executable_file: %s\n", file);
    if (stat(file, &sb) != 0) {
        printf("There seems to be an error: %s\n", file);
        perror("Error:");
        return 0;
    }
    
    if (S_ISREG(sb.st_mode)) {
        int isExecutable = access(file, X_OK); 
        if (isExecutable != 0) {
            perror("Error:");
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I run my program the behavior is confusing me. In one directory it lists all executable files, while in another directory it doesn't list any.

I located the file of concern and figured this out:

Output of my function:

> is_executable_file: .
>
> is_executable_file: c-get-exec-list
> There seems to be an error: c-get-exec-list
> Error:: No such file or directory
>
> is_executable_file: ..

I then checked with `ls -l` to get further information about the file:

> total 836
> -rwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 854304 May  9 22:36 c-get-exec-list

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

FYI: The file of concern is the program that I'm currently working on. I don't know if that has something to do why it fails.

Comment: It appears to work correctly when I test it.  I'd try: (1) print the file names you are testing, to make sure they're what you think, and compare with `ls -l`; (2) make sure you are in the correct directory so that the file can be found with the path you are passing; (3) check the return values of `stat` and `access` separately, to determine which one is failing, and `perror` to see what fails.

Comment: @NateEldredge I just checked everything again and it seems that my access function returns `-1` and this confuses me. I have two executable files and my function only returns true for one of them. They are in different folders though. What might be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: I think we need a MRE here.  Turn this into a complete program with a simple `main` function and error checking (with `perror` whenever a system call fails), and show us the exact way you run it, along with `ls -l` output of the files in question and all their parent directories.

Comment: @NateEldredge I've updated my question and added further information. Tell me if you more information.

Comment: You're sure that the current working directory at the time of the call is actually the directory where `c-get-exec-list` is located?  Often when you run a program from inside an IDE, the working directory is not what you think.  You could try calling `getcwd()` right before to verify.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, I am pretty certain. I'm compiling it with a Makefile and then execute the program. Hence no IDE available.